# Bug WSO2Integration Studio http endpoint character (<,>)

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am looking for a rest api in Wso2 Integration Studio. Does not support > and < signs in http endpoint URL. These marks >
I used the expression. But that doesn't save my change.

The example is below.

[image]

Comment: What is the Integration Studio version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` character entities to represent `<` and `>` respectively?

URI template would be

```
http://localhost:8000/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?year&gt;{uri.var.ep.year}
```

Comment: I already tried the solution you suggested. But Integration Studio doesn't save this change while saving it. So I can't try this solution